# Why python methods are stored in different addresses?

Tags: python, methods, attributes

```
<built-in method sort of list object at 0x10794e488>
>>> [].sort
<built-in method sort of list object at 0x10794e6c8>
>>> [].sort
<built-in method sort of list object at 0x10794e488>
>>> [].sort
<built-in method sort of list object at 0x10794e6c8>
```

Why python methods are stored in two different addresses?

Comment: The address is the address of the list, not the method. You are creating a new list each time

Answer (score 6):

it's not the address of the method, but of the object.

you create a new list object each time.

if you save it in a variable, you'll get the same address (and for all methods...)

```py
>>> a = []
>>> a.sort
<built-in method sort of list object at 0x7f78138fa688>
>>> a.sort
<built-in method sort of list object at 0x7f78138fa688>
>>> a.count
<built-in method sort of list object at 0x7f78138fa688>
>>> a.index
<built-in method sort of list object at 0x7f78138fa688>
>>>
```